# Get data from custom middleware in django views

Tags: python, django

I've followed [this](https://www.stavros.io/posts/django-page-load-time/) link to create a custom middleware.

The main idea is I want to show the page rendering time on my index.html page.
My middleware object:

```
class StatsMiddleware(object):
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    return self.get_response(request)

def process_request(self, request):
    request.start_time = time.time()

def process_response(self, request, response):
    duration = time.time() - request.start_time

    response["render_time"] = int(duration * 1000)
    return response
```

How can I process this response object via my class-based views?

Comment: Just another approach: send this time as shown in your tutorial. And display it via one-liner in JS: get it from response headers and put it into some `<p>` tag for example

Comment: You won't be able to include it in your class based views because you won't have it at that point. The processing of the views is part of what you're timing. Satevg's approach sounds like a reasonable one.